# When is Hom(G, H) the same size as Hom(H, G)?

Tags: gr.group-theory, co.combinatorics, finite-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be finite groups. Consider the ratio

$$r_{G, H} \equiv {|Hom(G, H)| \over{|Hom(H,G)|}}$$

My question is

> When is $r_{G, H} = 1$? Can we characterize the pairs of groups $(G, H)$ for which this occurs?

One can answer the corresponding problem in $Set$. Let $S$ and $T$ be finite sets. A straightforward counting argument shows that

$$r_{S, T} = 1 \iff |T|^{|S|} = |S|^{|T|}$$

In the case of groups one can use another counting argument to obtain the bounds

$$|H|^{-|G|} \leq r_{G, H} \leq |G|^{|H|}$$

It seems that these bounds are not very useful though; as $|G|$ and $|H|$ grow the lower bound goes to 0 and the upper bound goes to $\infty$.

So far we have:

- $r_{G, H} = 1$ if $G$ and $H$ are abelian (Tom Goodwillie).
- $r_{G, H} = 1$ if $G$ and $H$ are simple and not subgroups of one another (Alex Bartel and Richard Kent).

My guess is that this is a big problem in the general case, since counting homomorphisms [seems to involve](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405122) heavy machinery even in special cases. So I'd appreciate necessary and sufficient conditions for special classes of groups, or references to relevant literature.

---

Edit: The original question was "When is $r_{G, H} < 1$?". I've changed it in light of the comments, with the hope that the new version is more interesting and tractable.

Comment: Have you looked at the abelian case yet?

Comment: If they are both abelian then the numbers are equal.

Comment: I don't see what kind of answer you can hope for. There will be some small number of cases where $r_{G,H}=1$. (Including where both groups are abelian, as Tom Goodwillie points out.) In every other case, either $r_{G,H}$ or $r_{H,G}$ will be $<1$. So the answer is "a little less than half the time." 

Comment: I think the question was more in the spirit of, "If someone hands you groups $G$ and $H$, is there a nice way of determining which hom-set is larger?"

Comment: Another easy case is when $G$ is simple and not a subgroup of $H$. Then $|Hom(G,H)|=1$, while a quotient of $H$ might still inject into $G$. But I think this example is indicative of the fact that the result will depend so much on the exact structure of the groups that you are unlikely to get a nice result in full generality.

Comment: Tom, does the proof also indicate whether being abelian is necessary? In light of David and Alex's comments I might change the problem to "When is $r_{G, H} = 1$?", which is perhaps more amenable to a nice result.

Comment: Luke, as Alex's comment indicates, the ratio could be 1 when both $G$ and $H$ are simple and not subgroups of each other.

Comment: Richard, thanks for pointing that out. It seems that pinning down when the ratio is 1 isn't immediately trivial, and so I'll change the question to focus on this perhaps more tractable problem.

Comment: This problem looks extraordinarily difficult. Is there a chance of solving it in the case of solvable groups? 

Comment: By the way, is $Hom(G,H)$ to be interpreted as equivalence classes of homomorphisms modulo inner automorphisms on both sides or as genuine homomorphisms? That would make a difference.

Comment: If this was a question in combinatorics then you'd have the option of a probabilistic answer.  Does anyone know or have any ideas on how to apply this sort of technique to `random groups'?

Comment: Alex, I had intended it $Hom(G, H)$ to mean genuine homomorphisms.

Comment: Another (perhaps silly) way to look at the problem: How can we characterize the kernel (in some sense) of the map $r(G,H): Grp \times Grp \to \mathbb{Q}^{\times}$? I haven't studied much category theory so I'm not sure if there is a reasonable definition of kernel that applies, and don't know whether it would be helpful or not. Actually, I'm not even sure that the function $r$ exists in any meaningful sense since Grp is a large category.

Comment: I don't think that looking at the category theory angle will help too much for this problem, although it's still a good comment.  When you have some kind of duality in your category it makes perfect sense to formulate it in this way.  Perhaps "Landrock's Lemma" is of interest, which applies for certain categories of group representations.